# Is there a way to use a variable in a tag name in RSLogix5000?

Tags: plc

I have a bunch of tags in the form of `tank_#`. I also have tags called `tank_desc_#`. Based on the `tank_#` of the process, I want to store the `tank_desc_#`. In my head I think I want something like `tank_desc_[tank_#]`. I've seen this in another program with a `BOOL` tag so I tried to implement that with a `COP` tag. In the other tag, the tag is `ShiftRegister[Number].BoolAddress`. In my `COP` I tried, `COP(tank_desc_[tank_#],Current_Tank_Desc,1)`. This just gives me an error though.

I was able to get the data that I want by just setting it at the end of each rung that assigns the current rung. I feel like this is excessive and there's gotta be a better way that I could use one rung and one instruction.

Edit- I've simplified the actual PLC logic slightly and hopefully made a slightly better description below.

The tags are in the form of:

```
Current_Tank
```

and

```
Tank_Desc_1
Tank_Desc_2
Tank_Desc_3
Tank_Desc_4
Tank_Desc_5
Tank_Desc_6
Tank_Desc_7
Tank_Desc_8
Tank_Desc_9
Tank_Desc_10
```

and were created as individual tags and are not in arrays. The `Current_Tank` is an integer representing the individual tank numbers (1-10). I want to use the `Current_Tank` to easily copy the string stored in the `Tank_Desc`s to a new variable `Current_Tank_Desc` without having to append a `COP(Tank_Desc_1...10,Current_Tank_Desc,1` for each `Tank_Desc_`.

in short I want to combine the string "Tank_Desc_" and the value of `Current_Tank` to get `Tank_Desc_[Current_Tank]`.

Comment: What is the error message in COP? It looks to me like you're trying to work with Arrays, am I right? Do you want to reference an element in a array using a variable as a index?

Comment: The error message is: `COP, Operand 0: Referenced tag is undefined.`  As far as the array goes- no the tag creator made 10 individual `desc`s and `tank_#`s.

Comment: I was able to create a new array for the descriptions and then use that to "streamline" to achieve the desired result. If you want to make an answer suggesting that, I can mark as the answer. Bonus points if there's a way to do it without the array.

Comment: I don't see how not to use an array or an indexer to copy the value from one memory to another based on an index, this still sounds to me like a good practice, but resources really vary from PLC to PLC and Logix can be difficult to deal with that (I don't know Rockwell PLCs in depth). If you got the solution by yourself, please post it to help others! ;)